# Why is my merge function giving me a segfault?

Tags: c++, mergesort

Today in my CS class we learned about the more efficient sorts, specifically merge and quick sorts. I am trying to write a merge sort, but I am having trouble with my code. I seem to be getting a segfault here, and I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong, or possible multiple things I am doing incorrectly. I'm open to learning, so feel free to suggest any improvements.

```
void mergeFunc(Person A[], int low, int mid, int high, Person B[])
    {
        int i, j, k;
        i = low, j = mid + 1, k = low; //i indexes first half, j indexes second, k indexes new array
        while(i <= mid && j <= high)
        {
            if(A[i].firstName < A[j].firstName) //If first half has smaller item, add it to new list
            {
                B[k] = A[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            else //Otherwise i and j are equal or j is smaller, so add it instead
            {
                B[k] = A[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        if(i > mid) //If i has gone past its part of the array, add the rest of j to the new array
        {
           B[k] = A[j];
           k++;
        }
        else //Otherwise add the rest of i
        {
            B[k] = A[i];
            k++;
        }
        for(k = low; k <= high; k++) //Copy the new array back to A
        {
            A[k] = B[k];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just as a future thing to help you figure something like this: step through the program with gdb and you can see exactly what line it segfaults on. Mark a breakpoint in the code to skip the irrelevant stuff and then step through it past the breakpoint. http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_gdb.html

Comment: You need two loops after the main `while` loop because there could be more than one element from the bottom of the array left to copy, or more than one element from the top of the array.  Only one of the loops will do anything.

Comment: You probably overflow the bounds of `A` or `B`.

Comment: What is the definition of `Person`?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all of the lower half of the array comes before any of the upper half of the array.  Your code only copies one element of the upper half of the array into the B array, which is not really adequate.

```
void mergeFunc(Person A[], int low, int mid, int high, Person B[])
{
    assert(low >= 0 && low <= mid && mid <= high);
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = low;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (A[i].firstName < A[j].firstName)
            B[k++] = A[i++];
        else
            B[k++] = A[j++];
    }
    while (j <= high)
       B[k++] = A[j++];
    while (i <= mid)
        B[k++] = A[i++];
    for (k = low; k <= high; k++)
        A[k] = B[k];
}
```

This code is more compact and more nearly idiomatic C because it makes better use of the increment operators.